# can't send viewable html file containing nav bar leading to multiple pages

Tags: html

I wrote something like this for different html pages, but doesn't show because the html files are local, how do I send them all? (not too complicated please, I'm a beginner)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color: grey">
<head>
  <style>
    #div1 {
      background-image: linear-gradient(darkred, red); 
      border-radius: 15px; 
      padding: 10px;
      font-family:"Lucida Handwriting", cursive; 
      color: white
    }
     .topnav {
      background-color: #333;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    }

    /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
    .topnav a {
      font-family:"Lucida Handwriting", cursive;
      float: left;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 1px 107px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    /* Change the color of links on hover */
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: grey;
      color: black;
    }
    
    /* Add a color to the active/current link */
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: darkred;
      color: white;
    } 
    .center {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 50%;
    }
  </style>
  
</head>
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="file:///C:/Users/Anas/Desktop/TNL1PROWEB/HTML/home.html">Accueil</a>
    <a href="file:///C:/Users/Anas/Desktop/TNL1PROWEB/HTML/Classement.html">Classement</a>
    <a href="file:///C:/Users/Anas/Desktop/TNL1PROWEB/HTML/stats.html">Statistiques</a>
     <a href="file:///C:/Users/Anas/Desktop/TNL1PROWEB/HTML/Matchs&resultats.html">Matchs & Resultats</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: use relative paths: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: I want to send them to people by email, so they can see it.. thnx